# C++ pointer container with reference counting

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I need a collection in which i can store heap-allocated objects having virtual functions.

I known about `boost::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` (C++11) and `boost::ptr_(vector|list|map)`, but they doesn't solve duplicate pointer problem.

Just to describe a problem - i have a function which accepts heap-allocated pointer and stores it for future use:

```
void SomeClass::add(T* ptr)
{
  _list.push_back(ptr);
}
```

But if i call `add` twice with same parameter `ptr` - `_list` will contain two pointers to same object and when `_list` is destructed multiple deletion of same object will occur.

If `_list` will count pointer which he stores and uses them at deletion time then this problem will be solved and objects will not be deleted multiple times.

**So the question is:**

Does somebody knows some library with collections (vector,list,map in essence) of pointer with auto-delete on destruction and support of reference counting?

Or maybe i can solve this problem using some other technique?

**Update:**

I need support of duplicate pointers. So i can't use `std::set`.

As [Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8774779/809107) and [Grizzly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8774799/809107) mentioned - it is a bad idea to use raw pointers in general and suggests to use `std::make_shared` and forget about instantiation via `new`. But this is responsibility of client-side code - not the class which i designs. Even if i change `add` signature (and `_list` container of course) to

```
void SomeClass::add(std::shared_ptr<T> ptr)
{
   _list.push_back(ptr);
}
```

then somebody (who doesn't know about `std::make_shared`) still can write this:

```
SomeClass instance;
T* ptr = new T();
instance.add(ptr);
instance.add(ptr);
```

So this is not a full solution which i wait, but useful if you write code alone.

**Update 2:**

As an alternative solution i found a clonning (using generated copy constructor). I mean that i can change my `add` function like this:

```
template <typename R>
void SomeClass::add(const R& ref)
{
  _list.push_back(new R(ref));
}
```

this will allow virtual method (R - class which extends some base class (interface)) calls and disallow duplicate pointers. But this solution has an overhead for clone.

Comment: How about storing the shared pointers?  If one gets destroyed, the other's still valid.  Only when both are destroyed  (and no other shared pointers exist to the same object) does the object they point to get destroyed as well.

Comment: Deleting two `shared_ptr`s to the same object will only destroy the object once, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That will only work, if one of the two `shared_ptrs` is created by copying the other, not when creating both from raw pointers, which is what add seems to want to do

Comment: @Grizzly: Or if you use intrusive counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: `std::list<std::shared_ptr<T>>`.

The shared pointer is avaiable from `<memory>`, or on older platforms from `<tr1/memory>`, or from Boost's `<boost/shared_ptr.hpp>`. You won't need to delete *anything* manually, as the shared pointer takes care of this itself. You will however need to keep *all* your heap pointers inside a shared pointer right from the start:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> p(new T);    // legacy
auto p = std::make_shared<T>(); // better
```

If you another shared pointer to the same object, make a copy of the shared pointer (rather than construct a new shared pointer from the underlying raw pointer): `auto q = p;`

The moral here is: If you're using naked pointers, something is wrong.

Comment: He's saying he's constructing two `shared_ptr`s with the same pointer which causes a double-delete

Answer (score 1):

Realize that smart pointers are compared by comparing the underlying container. So you can just use a `std::set` of whatever smartpointer you prefer. Personally I use `std::unique_ptr` over `shared_ptr`, whenever I can get away with it, since it makes the ownership much clearer (whoever holds the `unique_ptr`is the owner) and has much lower overhead too. I have found that this is enough for almost all my code. The code would look something like the following:

```
std::set<std::unique_ptr<T> > _list;

void SomeClass::add(T* ptr)
{
   std::unique_ptr<T> p(ptr);
   auto iter = _list.find(p);
   if(iter == _list.end())
     _list.insert(std::move(p));
   else
     p.release();
}
```

I'm not sure right now if that is overkill (have to check if `insert` is guaranteed not to do anything, if the insertion fails), but it should work. Doing this with `shared_ptr<T>` would look similar, although be a bit more complex, due to the lack of a `relase` member. In that case I would probably first construct a `shared_ptr<T>` with a do nothing `deleter` too pass to the call to find and then another `shared_ptr<T>` which is actually inserted.

Of course personally I would avoid doing this and always pass around smart pointers when the ownership of a pointer changes hands. Therefore I would rewrite `SomeClass::add` as `void SomeClass::add(std::unique_ptr<T> ptr)` or `void SomeClass::add(std::shared_ptr<T> ptr)` which would pretty much solve the problem of having multiple instances anyways (as long as the pointer is always wrapped).

Comment: This is somewhat dangerous because it's unclear to the user that this function takes ownership of the pointer, sometimes.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I do realize that, but as I see it that's what the question asks for. But know that you remind me, I did want to add a note why that was a bad idea.